# replace log4j version in jasypt spring boot starter

Tags: spring-boot, maven, log4j, jasypt

I am using jasypt-spring-boot-starter 3.0.4 dependency in my project and I want to remove the log4j dependency.

The issue is that the jasypt dependency requires log4j-bom 2.14.1 but that version is no longer available in the company Nexus repository(because of the recently discovered vulnerabilities).
Is there any way I can exclude the log4j dependency or replace it with a newer version?

The project is build using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.5.

These are my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-jasypt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where spring-boot.version = 2.5.5, spring-boot-jasypt.version=3.0.4 and log4j2.version = 2.17.1.

This is the maven error: **Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.4: Failure to find org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom:pom:2.14.1**

Thanks

Comment: Simply add newer version of log4j to your own pom or check if the updated version of spring-boot already picking up newer versions I would also check if you are really using log4j... not logback?

Comment: @khmarbaise thank for the answer. I have updated the description with the pom dependencies. I have tried to update spring boot to the latest version that included the log4j update but with no success..

Comment: The easiest solution is upgrading `spring-boot-starter-parent` to version `2.5.9`.

Comment: I have tried that and for log4j-impl and log4j-api, the correct version is downloaded-2.17.1. However it also tries to download log4j-bom 2.14.1 for some reason and this is actually the problem..